# Why is it that the inBetween function uses the current numbers when it should use the previous ones

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, logic

The goal is that the program creates 3 randomly generated numbers then if the deal button is pressed those 3 numbers go in the inBetween function then should echo then create new random numbers but what's happening is the inBetween function uses the current generated numbers instead of the previous one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    session_start();

    function isBetween($num1, $num2, $num3)
    {
        $numbers = [$num1, $num2];

        if ($num3 > min($numbers) && $num3 < max($numbers)) {
            return $num3 . " Is Between " . min($numbers) . " and " . max($numbers) . "<br/>";
        } else {
            return $num3 . " Is Not Between " . min($numbers) . " and " . max($numbers) . "<br/>";
        }
    }

    $num1 = rand(0, 9);
    $num2 = rand(0, 9);
    $num3 = rand(0, 9);

    if (isset($_POST['btn1'])) {

        if ($_SESSION['round'] >= 10) {
            echo "Game Over";
            session_destroy();
            exit;
        }

        $choice = $_POST['btn1'];

        if ($choice == "deal") {
            echo isBetween($num1, $num2, $num3);
            echo "You Pressed Deal <br />";
        } else {
            echo "You Pressed No Deal <br />";
        }

        $_SESSION['round']++;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['round'] = 1;
    }

    echo $num1 . "<br />";
    echo $num2 . "<br />";
    echo $num3 . "<br />";
    ?>

    <form method='POST'>
        <button type="submit" class="btnDeal" name="btn1" value="deal">Deal</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btnNodeal" name="btn1" value="nodeal">No Deal</button>
        <p>Round <?php echo $_SESSION['round'] ?></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Dunno what to do next

Comment: Aside: You don't need to put the numbers in an array. You can use `min($num1, $num2)`

Comment: Every time you submit the form it generates new random numbers. If you want to use the values from a previous submission, save them in session variables.

Comment: Just `sort()` the numbers so that you don't need to call `min()` or `max()`, ever. You already know how to preserve data in the session array; there is nothing to teach you.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the page loads, PHP is going to go through your whole code, in the order it's written. It won't remember where it got to last time, or jump to a particular part.

Here's your description of the intention:

1. if the deal button is pressed ...
2. ... those 3 numbers go in the inBetween function
3. ... then should echo
4. ... then create new random numbers

But here's what your code does:

1. `$num1 = rand(0, 9); ...`
2. `if ($choice == "deal") { ...`
3. `echo isBetween($num1, $num2, $num3);`
4. `echo $num1 . "<br />"; ...`

Clearly these don't match, step 4 of your intended list has become step 1. To move it around, you need some other place to get `$num1` etc from - the obvious place being the same place you already get the number of rounds, the session.

So we can expand the outline a bit:

1. if the deal button is pressed ...
2. ... retrieve the previous numbers from the session
3. ... those 3 numbers go in the inBetween function
4. ... then should echo
5. ... then create new random numbers
6. ... and store the new numbers in the session